# How should I access the value in this hash structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After the usage from the params function I get the following output if i print it out with puts function

```
{"{:value =>\"12\"}"=>""}
```

How should I access these, that I get 12?

Comment: how did you exactly end up with that hash?

Comment: It looks like your params are malformed or your params parsing isn't correctly interpreting params.

Comment: What do you mean by `usage from the params function`? Also post the relevant code so that we can debug it.

Comment: `<%= hidden_field :post_id, value: params[:id] %>`
`id = params[:post_id]`
`puts id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
h =  {"{:value =>\"12\"}"=>""}
#this will return "{:value =>\"12\"}"
h.first[0]
#this will convert from string to hash
real_hash = eval(h.first[0])
#this will return 12
real_hash[:value]
```